# How can I check if a domain's mail server is hosted by me?

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server

I do have a reseller package at TSO Host that lets me manage web hosting for other domains. At the moment I'm trying to figure out if a specific domain that once has been hosted is still sending/receiving mail using our mail servers - http://baglanfuneralhome.co.uk/

What I've done so far:
Do a DNS lookup to check which name servers are responsible for this domain. It's not the name servers of my host (tsohost.com), but of topwebspacehosting.co.uk/. This lets me assume that the website (webspace) is hosted there.

Do a MX lookup: This only gives back the same domain I've entered. Does that mean that, since it's the same domain I've already done a DNS lookup for, the mail servers are also managed by topwebspacehosting.co.uk?

```
Mx Record   baglanfuneralhome.co.uk
```

Comment: The MX lookup should return at least a resolvable host. That host is the actual mailserver. (There could be many such entries). You have to add the MX pointing to your server to the authoritative DNS for your zone (you mentioned that as "some other host").

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Looking up "example.com" lists only one entry called "example.com" with preference 0 - does that mean the domain's email traffic also gets routed through the other host? I don't want this domain's mails to go through my environment, I want to verify that it's not.

Comment: You know, if you told us the actual domain name we could provide more helpful answers.

Comment: @joeqwerty Alright, there you go. Please enlighten me, I'd like to learn :)

Comment: if example.com is resolvable (A record) then yes, that is your MX server too.

Comment: if you are responsinle for msul checl the logs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MX record is pointing to the domain literal, which means that any email will be going to the server that resolves to the literal domain name baglanfuneralhome.co.uk. This probably means that there is no mail server installed that is actually accepting email for the domain. You can check with the party that's hosting that server and see, but my guess is that they aren't running a mail server on that host.